# Probability and shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, computer-science, probability

Suppose I have a directed network with "n" nodes and "d" arcs.  p(d) represents the probability that a package will arrive safely along that arc.  Multiplying all of the probabilities on each arc the package takes on its path provides the probability of the package arriving safely to its destination.

Is there a formula that would allow us to maximize the probability the package arrives safely in the form of a shortest path problem?

Answer (score 6):

Set up a graph where the weight on each arc d is -log(p(d)).

Then solve the shortest path problem, which finds the path with the smallest sum of weights.

This sum is:

```
-log(p(d0))-log(p(d1))-log(p(d2))... = -log(p(d0)*p(d1)*p(d2)...)
```

Therefore the smallest sum in neg log space is equivalent to the largest probability.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize this as a variation of a [MDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) problem where each node has an edge that leads to a dummy state which only has a loop edge on itself.
This state represents the package being damages/compromised and the edges leading to it have a very high cost.
The rest is pretty straightforward, you set the probability and the other costs with a lower amount (e.g. 100 for the edges leading to the "damaged" state including the loop, 1 for the other edges) except the edge leading to the destination state that is to be set with a high negative value (e.g. -500).

Once you've set the problem you can run Policy Iteration or Value Iteration to obtain the best policy (edges to move on) to send the package to destination. They will converge giving you the safest path as possible.

This is quite easy if you're familiar with MDPs.